# Remove elements within a list of indexes in python

Tags: python, list, remove-if

I have a list of values:

```
list_of_value = [1,3,4,2,3,"start",3,4,5,"stop",5,6,7,6,"start",5,6,7,"stop"]
```

I need to remove from the list the elements between "start" and "stop" (boundaries included).

The output should be something like:

```
[1,3,4,2,3,5,6,7,6]
```

I tried something like this:

```
for i, el in enumerate(list_of_values):
    if "start" in el:
        start_index = i
    if "stop" in el:
        stop_index = i
        for a in range(start_index,stop_index):
            del list_of_values[a]
```

but it's not working.

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Davide

Comment: create a new list, and add the value which are not in start and end index, and ignore the between values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is that you have a variable called `flag` to know when to append values to your output. It will only append after `stop` and not between `start` and `stop`

```
output = []
flag = False
for el in list_of_values:
    if "start" == el and not flag:
        flag = True
    if "stop" == el:
        flag = False
        continue
    if not flag:
        output.append(el)
```

Comment: If it helps, mark this as an answer ;) Thanks